# Python regular expressions word bounaries

Tags: python, regex

Hello I have a text string like this below and I am trying to use regular expressions to extract the Total Sales quantity which can be found right after the new line after the Total Sales\n43 for example 43 would the total sales. I am using the following command but I want to drop the Total Sales and the \n and just keep the quantity.  I am wondering how I might go about this or will I need to do additional processing.  Thanks

```
'\ufeffSacramento Association of REALTORS®\nSingle Family Home Sales by ZIP CODE\nJanuary 2020\nZip        
 Code\nCurrent Month\nLast Month\nLast Year\nYear-to-Date\nTotal Sales\n43\nREO  
 Sales\n0\n45\n40\n43\nMedian Sales Price\n$417,000\n$0\n$410,000\n$400,000\n$417,000\nAverage    
 Price/Square Foot\n$268\nShort Sales\n0\n$253\n$239\nN/A\nAverage Sq Ft of  
 Property\n1,769\n$0\n1,746\n1,843\nN/A\nTotal Listing Inventory 
 *\n69\nConventional\n43\n65\n90\nN/A\nTotal Listing Median Price 
 ∞\n$612,475\nSales\n$417,000\n$574,900\n$547,475\nN/A\nTotal Sales\n29\nREO 
 **strong text**Sales\n0\n37\n16\n29\nMedian Sales Price\n$369,000
```

I am using a command like this:

```
 total_sales = re.findall(r'\bTotal Sales\n\d{2}',data)
```

which returns:

```
 ['Total Sales\n43',
 'Total Sales\n29',
 'Total Sales\n29',
 'Total Sales\n32',
 'Total Sales\n30',
 'Total Sales\n52',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
re.findall(r'\bTotal Sales\n(\d*)',data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use positive look behind:`(?<=Total Sales\n)\d{2}`. This way it checks if the `Total Sales\n` string is preceding the pattern `\d{2}`. And only capture that.